# How to manually update a package on CoreOS?

Tags: upgrade, openssl, coreos

I am using CoreOS 493.0.0+2014-11-14-1501. This version of CoreOS is using OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014. When I manually try to update using `update_engine_client -update` the update fails and I see the following exception in the logs (in `journalctl -ru udpate-engine`:

```
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:payload_state.cc(400)] Current URL Index = 0
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:payload_state.cc(257)] Resetting the current URL index (0) to 0 as we only have 1 URL(s)
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:payload_state.cc(97)] Updating payload state for error code: 18 (kActionCodeDownloadPayloadPubKeyVerification
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:ERROR:update_attempter.cc(787)] Update failed.
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:update_attempter.cc(460)] Processing Done.
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:action_processor.cc(73)] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: finished last action of type DownloadAction
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:action_processor.cc(68)] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: DownloadAction action failed. Aborting processing.
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:ERROR:download_action.cc(118)] Download of https://update.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/1068.8.0/update.gz failed
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000f0 : 8a e0 af 10 58 76 f6 c1 dd a5 c5 f3 98 51 05 6e
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000e0 : ae 7f e9 2f a0 a0 ba fb 7c 19 af c6 1a 65 a3 f5
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000d0 : 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000c0 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 30 31 30
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000b0 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000a0 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000090 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000080 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000070 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000060 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000050 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000040 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000030 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000020 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000010 : ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000000 : 00 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(251)] Logging array of length: 256
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(861)] Computed Signature:
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000f0 : 6f 1e c4 e8 66 1f 8b 31 db 78 ac 9b 69 04 bd 5a
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000e0 : 3c 4c 71 bf a5 d6 47 86 05 e0 f5 d8 30 98 0b 90
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000d0 : b0 c7 3e 2d 29 23 88 7f 9b 8a e4 a4 de 39 1e 01
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000c0 : 7b 17 de 97 99 d4 89 07 c7 39 10 eb 50 ca 7d 9d
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000b0 : 32 e2 e8 07 ae 07 cf 77 c6 9a 46 6d f3 c9 ac 44
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x000000a0 : 87 01 10 cd 40 ce ce 49 b2 8e bf aa d0 57 06 26
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000090 : 94 4c ce 4c 91 df 4a 8c 37 1a 13 7f c8 7f 5a 72
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000080 : 36 9c 8a b3 20 09 b8 95 ae 10 e9 3e 8b 63 62 e9
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000070 : f4 29 63 42 2a 09 28 dd 3f 8c 5a 0a 4d 68 e2 ee
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000060 : 65 2c ce 16 1b 21 25 03 e2 80 89 c6 76 67 d7 74
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000050 : 40 9f be e9 e9 2b 2c e1 72 11 b9 30 05 2d 08 a8
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000040 : 38 88 23 c3 e1 d6 49 42 05 10 db ca 32 89 f0 ad
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000030 : 8b 16 98 92 7c 2c 11 6a 0a bd 55 97 e6 18 1b 3b
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000020 : 41 7e 2d 3a 16 19 d7 48 1e 98 07 80 17 77 f5 af
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000010 : aa ea 13 e6 f4 c0 d8 de ed 7a 3e 3b 9e 3b 04 f8
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(268)] 0x00000000 : 58 a4 b9 9e 5f 63 27 f3 79 b3 9d 52 54 a5 4b 07
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:utils.cc(251)] Logging array of length: 256
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:ERROR:delta_performer.cc(858)] Public key verification failed, thus update failed. Attached Signature:
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:payload_signer.cc(265)] signature size = 528
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:delta_performer.cc(821)] Verifying delta payload using public key: /usr/share/update_engine/update-payload-ke
Aug 04 09:02:52 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090252:INFO:update_attempter.cc(597)] Download status: inactive
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(141)] Done w/ all transfers
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(107)] TransferEnded w/ code 200
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(150)] Received transfer complete.
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(318)] Transfer completed (200), 217528649 bytes downloaded
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(261)] HTTP response code: 200
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 1017/1017 operations (100%), 217528649/217528649 bytes downloaded (100%),
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:delta_performer.cc(738)] Extracted signature data of size 528 at 217471746
Aug 04 09:02:51 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090251:INFO:delta_performer.cc(767)] Skipping hash verification for signature operation 1017
Aug 04 09:02:42 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090242:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 903/1017 operations (88%), 200129083/217528649 bytes downloaded (92%), ove
Aug 04 09:02:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090235:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 782/1017 operations (76%), 182729275/217528649 bytes downloaded (84%), ove
Aug 04 09:02:29 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090229:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 684/1017 operations (67%), 160971323/217528649 bytes downloaded (74%), ove
Aug 04 09:02:22 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090222:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 611/1017 operations (60%), 131553851/217528649 bytes downloaded (60%), ove
Aug 04 09:02:11 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090211:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 509/1017 operations (50%), 112007739/217528649 bytes downloaded (51%), ove
Aug 04 09:02:03 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090203:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 416/1017 operations (40%), 87013947/217528649 bytes downloaded (40%), over
Aug 04 09:01:59 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090159:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 346/1017 operations (34%), 60193339/217528649 bytes downloaded (27%), over
Aug 04 09:01:53 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090153:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 204/1017 operations (20%), 45529659/217528649 bytes downloaded (20%), over
Aug 04 09:01:45 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090145:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 96/1017 operations (9%), 26106427/217528649 bytes downloaded (12%), overal
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:delta_performer.cc(404)] Starting to apply update payload operations
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:delta_performer.cc(940)] Verifying source partitions.
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:delta_performer.cc(277)] PartitionInfo new_rootfs_info sha256: Opa16PO0hOn0JqGW7V7sLgqWZE/EC4G40BDF5gM27ds= s
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:delta_performer.cc(153)] Completed 0/? operations, 294/217528649 bytes downloaded (0%), overall progress 0%
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(448)] Setting up timeout source: 1 seconds.
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(185)] Setting up curl options for HTTPS
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(51)] We are connected via Ethernet, Updates allowed: Yes
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:libcurl_http_fetcher.cc(62)] Starting/Resuming transfer
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(57)] starting transfer of range 0+?
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:multi_range_http_fetcher.cc(29)] starting first transfer
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:update_attempter.cc(597)] Download status: active
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:install_plan.cc(52)] InstallPlan: , new_update, url: https://update.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/1068.8.0/up
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: [0804/090135:INFO:action_processor.cc(82)] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: finished OmahaRequestAction, starting DownloadActio
Aug 04 09:01:35 coreos update_engine[562]: </response>
```

Hence, I was planning to just manually update OpenSSL on this machine. I tried googling around but updating CoreOS seemed to be the only way to go about doing is. I tried doing `dnf -y install opensssl` in the expectation that installs work the way they work on ubuntu: install if not present and update otherwise. However, dnf isn't installed on this machine. I tried using yum as well, but yum too isn't present.

How do I update openssl on this machine?

Comment: The official website docs https://coreos.com/products/coreupdate/docs/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: @GAD3R: `updateservicectl` is not available on this version of coreos

Comment: You can get it from here https://github.com/coreos/updateservicectl/releases

Comment: This requires go to be installed on the machine. Is there nothing out-of-the-box that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many other Linux CoreOS does not have a package manager.  The root filesystem is provided as one atomic image.  Applications deployed by users are generally deployed in Linux based containers like systemd-nspawn, Docker, rkt, runc, etc.

`updateservicectl` is a tool used for the administration of the [Omaha](https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/942e8d0aeff04707bd6a7a86f72369bca3efe556/doc/ServerProtocol.md) server which serves the update payloads. In this case, you are already using the correct tool - `update_engine_client`.

When a version of CoreOS is booted it's updated should be occurring automatically (unless they've been disabled).  Thus to view the *current* version (not necessarily) the version which was deployed at boot time run the command:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Container Linux by CoreOS"
ID=coreos
VERSION=1576.1.0
VERSION_ID=1576.1.0
BUILD_ID=2017-10-26-0503
PRETTY_NAME="Container Linux by CoreOS 1576.1.0 (Ladybug)"
ANSI_COLOR="38;5;75"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://issues.coreos.com"
COREOS_BOARD="amd64-usr"
```

Finally, you mentioned that your version is `493.0.0+2014-11-14-1501`.  Generally the `+2014-11-14-1501` denotes a development version or one that  was compiled from scratch.  Images like that would likely not have the GPG public keys baked into them to receive updates from the host referenced in your logs `update.release.core-os.net`. This leaves you with two choices:

1. If you built the image yourself, use the SDK to produce a new update payload with the updated packages that you need and serve it with the development Omaha server included in the SDK.  This is just a cherryPy utility which is trivial to run.
2. Update the host to a production image.  Generally this should not be done, but instead the host should be re-deployed.  To to this though one should identify the partition currently being used to server `/usr` and reference the CoreOS partition layout to choose the *inactive* partition.  From there one can manually download and apply the `update.gz` file using `dd` to the correct partition.  Explicit copy paste directions are intentionally not provided.  If this doesn't make sense, then in all likelihood you will destroy the OS and have catastrophic data loss.

Really, the best path to take is to tag any running containers and push them to a registry, backup the cloud-config (due to the era that this was deployed) and re-deploy.  If you wanted to minimize skew and watch the update process occur, you could even start from version [`494.0.0`](http://alpha.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/494.0.0/).